# How do I specify a java flag when building a project in SCons?

Tags: java, scons

I'm using SCons to build a Java project and I'm wondering if it's possible to specify some java flags. I'm specificaly looking for this one: `-enableassertion`

My scons SConstruct file look like that:

```
   env = Environment()
   env['JAVACLASSPATH'] = 'classes/:../../src/extlib/mlplot-v1.0.jar:.'

   class_files = env.Java(target = 'classes', source = 
        ['../../src/jlabos/', 'Cavity3d.java', 'MultiBlockUtils.java'])
   env.Jar(target = 'Cavity3d.jar', source = [class_files, 'Manifest.txt'])
```

Thanks for the suggestions (I do want to stick with scons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use JAVACFLAGS:

```
JAVACFLAGS
          General options that are passed to the Java compiler.
```

So something like this:

```
class_files = env.Java(target = 'classes', source = 
        ['../../src/jlabos/', 'Cavity3d.java', 'MultiBlockUtils.java'],
        JAVACFLAGS=['-enableassertion'])
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine (but not for enableassertion which is only for java and not javac, my bad.)

Comment: Ah! Glad to know. I use it for -g and -encoding, I didn't actually test -enableassertion :-)